# Converting JodaTime Duration to Java 8 time Duration: getStandardMinutes and other methods

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time

We're trying to convert a product that we have written using [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library to Java time due to some time zone wonkery in our country. (Daylight Saving Time DST is never consistent, and Joda-Time requires special manipulation and the use of offsets to get it to work properly).

I'm working with Joda-Time's [`Duration`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html). There are a number of methods such as [`getStandardMinutes`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#getStandardMinutes--).

Is there an easy way to achieve the same functionality on the Java 8+ [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html)? I'm assuming based on the code and comments that [`Duration::toMinutes`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toMinutes()) will not necessarily return the desired value.

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8's `Duration` class, a duration contains no reference date. Therefore all minutes you will extract are standard minutes. In JodaTime the comments for `getStandardXXX` specify explicitly, that a Duration assumes default length of day (24h/day, 60min/hour, 60sec/min ...). However this is only relevant, if you would want to apply a duration to a reference (date)time (for example, add this `Duration` to this `DateTime`), in which case adding a 'day' to a date flipping on daylight saving time might have unexpected effects (like an hour offset). However, for the `Duration` object this is irrelevant, as it effectively represents simply a duration in nanoseconds in 'real time', disregarding timezones and thelike.

In essence, you can use `toMinutes()` to get the exact amount of minutes as `long` value.

From the javadoc:

> Gets the number of minutes in this duration.
>
> This returns the total number of minutes in the duration by dividing the number of seconds by 60.
>
> This instance is immutable and unaffected by this method call.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much, @TreffnonX.

Answer (score 2):

## `java.time.Duration` = count of nanoseconds

As [TreffnonX already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58696235/642706), a `Duration` in *java.time* represents a span-of-time not attached to the timeline on a scale of 24-hour-days (without regard for calendar), hours, minutes, seconds, and fraction of a second. In other words, a **`java.time.Duration` is just a count of nanoseconds** with a bunch of handy methods.

## Span-of-time classes

Here is a graphical table I made to help orient you to the various span-of-time classes built into Java 8 and later, plus classes from the *ThreeTen-Extra* library.

FYI, all three projects ([*Joda-Time*,](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [*java-time*](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), and [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/)) are led by the same man, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen).

[image: Table of span-of-time classes in Java and in the ThreeTen-Extra project]